# Get positioning in order of a document in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine any structure:

```
collection/document
```

In every document there is a value, like some kind of *score*. Then I `order` my collection by this *score*: `collection("collection").orderBy("score")`.

I can retrieve a specific document out of this `collection("collection").orderBy("score").where(FieldPath.documentId(), "==", "document1234")`

Now I wonder whether or not it is possible to get the position of my specific document in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function trigger to your document which assigns the index. You position is then just the index field. You would need to add a trigger for onUpdate, onDelete aswell.

```
exports.updateScorePosition = functions.firestore.document('collection/{documentId}').onWrite(event => {
    return db.collection('collection').orderBy('points').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            let updatePointsBatch = db.batch();
            let i = 0;
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                updatePointsBatch.update(doc.ref, { index: i})
                i++;
            });
            return updatePointsBatch.commit();
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error: ' + error));
});
```

You could likely optimize this by only updating indexes after the current document index if you are working with a large collection

Comment: This is an option, but I surely do not want to waste a Function invocation for that. I would have an opportunity to do something like this in another Function, but I am not sure if it is a good idea to go through all documents on every invocation because my collection is very big, i.e. the size has an open end, which would make this super slow eventually.